# Homeomorphism $\phi : T^2/A \to X/B$. What are $ T^2/A$ and $X/B$?

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, visualization, quotient-spaces

The question I am working on asks me to construct a homeomorphism $\phi : T^2/A \to X/B$ where $T^2$, $A$, $X$ and $B$ are given as follows:

- $T^2=S^1 \times S^1$ and $A \subset T^2$ is given by $A=S^1 \times\{1\}$.
- $X=S^1 \times [-1, 1]$ and $B = S^1 \times\{-1, 1\}$.

But first of all, I do not know what the spaces $ T^2/A $ and $X/B$ 'look like', or what they are mathematically.

I can see that $A \subset T^2$ and $X \subset B$.

Can someone explain to me what they mean please? Then I can try and find an explicit homeomorphism between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T^2 = S^1\times S^1$ is a torus and $A = S^1\times\{1\}$ is one of the highlighted circles on torus below.

$\hspace{42mm}$[image]

$X = S^1\times[-1, 1]$ is a cylinder and $B = S^1\times\{-1, 1\}$ is the union of the boundary circles at each end.

The quotient $T^2/A$ is a torus with the circle $A$ collapsed to a point; depending on whether you collapse the purple circle or the red circle, you get two seemingly different spaces.

To visualise $X/B$, first collapse $S^1\times\{-1\}$ to a point and $S^1\times\{1\}$ to a point to obtain a sphere; these two points are the north and south pole. Then identify the south and north poles. Depending on whether you identify these two points on the inside or the outside of the sphere, you get two seemingly different spaces.

1. If you collapse the purple circle in the torus, you get the same space as you would get by identifying the north and south poles of a sphere by 'pushing them' inside to the centre.
2. If you collapse the red circle in the torus, you get the same space as you would be identifying the north and south poles of a sphere by 'pulling them' towards each other on the outside of the sphere.

Although these two spaces appear to be very different, they are in fact homeomorphic.

Comment: I see that $X/B$ is the reduced suspension $\Sigma \odot$ with the center point marked. But why is $T^2/A$ the pinched torus? Why can't I take the purple circunference and make the horn torus?

Comment: It depends on which circle you collapse. If you collapse the purple circle, you get the same as a sphere with the poles identified by pushing them towards the centre. If you collapse the red circle, you get a pinched torus (which is what you get if you identify the poles of the sphere by pulling them out towards each other). The result is the same up to homeomorphism.